# extract an element from a dictionary inside a list in a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let say we have a dataframe with the following format:

```
col1
[{'overall_prop': '0.812'}, {'overall_prop': '0.125'}, {'overall_prop': '0.062'}]
{}
```

The original data is in json format. I want to extract the value of `'overall_prop'` from the first element off the list in each row and here is what I tried to extract the first element:

```
 df['col1'].str[0]
```

everything is fine and then the following to extract `'overall_prop'`:

```
df['col1'].str[0].map(lambda x: x.get('overall_prop'))
```

but complained:

```
{AttributeError}'float' object has no attribute 'get'
```

because of `{}` (python dict object) that became `nan`

Then I tried this:

```
df['col1'].where(df['col1'].notna(), lambda x: [{}]).str[0].map(lambda x: x.get('overall_prop'))
```

but this time:

```
{TypeError}argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

In summary, I'm looking for a solution to extract an element from a dictionary inside a list that can handle null values.

Comment: did you try `df['col1'].str.map(lambda x: x[0]['overall_prop'])`

Comment: @JoeFerndz: StringMethods doesn't have map

Comment: my bad. i should have paid more attention. you can't use map on str. instead use `df.col1.apply(lambda x: x[0]['overall_prop'])`. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## EDIT Ver 1: col1 is list of dicts and x[0] has overall_prop

You can do this. Use `df.col1.apply(lambda x: x[0]['overall_prop'])` to get the first element from the list and the `overall_prop` value from the dictionary in the first element.

The assumption here is that each row in `col1` is a dictionary and has the key `overall_prop`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[[{'overall_prop': '0.001'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.002'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.003'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.004'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.005'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.006'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.007'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.008'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.009'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.010'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.011'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.012'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.013'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.014'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.015'}]]})

print (df)

df['overall_prop'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['overall_prop'])
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
                                                col1 overall_prop
0  [{'overall_prop': '0.001'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.001
1  [{'overall_prop': '0.004'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.004
2  [{'overall_prop': '0.007'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.007
3  [{'overall_prop': '0.010'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.010
4  [{'overall_prop': '0.013'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.013
```

## EDIT Ver 2: col1 is list of dicts and empty dict in list

If you have rows that do not have `overall_prop` as a key, you can use this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[[{'overall_prop': '0.001'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.002'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.003'}],
                           [{}],
                           [{'incorrect_key': '0.004'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.005'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.006'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.007'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.008'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.009'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.010'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.011'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.012'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.013'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.014'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.015'}]]})

import numpy as np

df['overall_prop'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['overall_prop'] if 'overall_prop' in x[0] else np.NaN)
```

The output of this will be:

```
                                                col1 overall_prop
0  [{'overall_prop': '0.001'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.001
1                                               [{}]          NaN
2  [{'incorrect_key': '0.004'}, {'overall_prop': ...          NaN
3  [{'overall_prop': '0.007'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.007
4  [{'overall_prop': '0.010'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.010
5  [{'overall_prop': '0.013'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.013
```

## EDIT Ver 3: col1 has varying types of data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[[{'overall_prop': '0.001'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.002'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.003'}],
                           [{}],
                           {'bad':'0.999'},
                           {},
                           'just a bad string',
                           250,
                           35.25,
                           True,
                           False,
                           (10,20),
                           [{'incorrect_key': '0.004'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.005'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.006'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.007'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.008'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.009'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.010'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.011'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.012'}],
                           [{'overall_prop': '0.013'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.014'},
                            {'overall_prop': '0.015'}]]})

def prop_check(x):
    if isinstance(x,list) and isinstance(x[0],dict) and 'overall_prop' in x[0]:
        return x[0]['overall_prop']
    else: return np.NaN

df['overall_prop'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: prop_check(x))
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
                                                 col1 overall_prop
0   [{'overall_prop': '0.001'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.001
1                                                [{}]          NaN
2                                    {'bad': '0.999'}          NaN
3                                                  {}          NaN
4                                   just a bad string          NaN
5                                                 250          NaN
6                                               35.25          NaN
7                                                True          NaN
8                                               False          NaN
9                                            (10, 20)          NaN
10  [{'incorrect_key': '0.004'}, {'overall_prop': ...          NaN
11  [{'overall_prop': '0.007'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.007
12  [{'overall_prop': '0.010'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.010
13  [{'overall_prop': '0.013'}, {'overall_prop': '...        0.013
```

Comment: As I said in the description, the problem is having an empty dictionary object in one of the rows that breaks everything.

Comment: Solved for that as well. See updated code at the bottom of my answer section

Comment: Thanks for updating the solution but still complaining: {TypeError}'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I think the reason is in your example, empty dic is inside the list. In my case, the empty dic is out of the list.

Comment: Got it. I am explicitly checking if it is a list and inside the list there is a dictionary and if that dictionary's first element is `overall_prop`. See if this solves